# Osdev linker multiple defintions inside docker error

Tags: c, docker, makefile, linker-errors, osdev

I was planning on working on my os after a long break. Back then I was working on a amd64 system so no issues building, but now since im working on my m1 mac I have to use docker. Suprisingly i still have my old computer and checked if my old build worked there and its 100% good. But the problem arises when I try to use docker to build it.

Here is the difference in makefiles (old=no docker), (new = with docker). [Diff changes](https://linediff.com/?id=64f4af54687f4be64f8b4567)

[Here](https://github.com/Bone-Project/BoneOS) is my github project

Now my errors arise with not compiling the "subdirs" but in this line(s) specifically:

```
#
# Link

$(BONEOS_BIN): $(libraries) $(LINKER_SCRIPT)
    $(LD) $(LDPARAMS) \
    -T $(LINKER_SCRIPT) \
    -o $@ \
    --start-group $(libraries) --end-group \
    -Map=BoneOS.map \
    -L$(LIBGCCDIR) -l$(LIBGCCNAME)
```

And I get these errors: https://pastebin.com/t7JHw0DX

which are multiple definition errors, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

If you were wondering, my final goal is that so it builds the iso image in the docker container, so then after I can pull the ISO image from the docker to my laptop and then can run the iso image here for myself.

Comment: Start with the first redefinition error. It is the `gp` variable and it is coming from gdt.h and shows up in the object file gdt.o and cpu.o . gdt.h is included in gdt.c and cpu.c . You have defined a structure with `struct gdt_ptr`... in gdt.h and defined a global variable `gp` of that type in the header. Every .c file that includes gdt.h will try to create its own copy of `gp`. Declare `struct gdt_ptr` in the gdt.h and define a variable of that type in gdt.c. You shouldn't define global variables in header files for this reason.

Comment: Of course in the gdt.h header file you would declare `gp` as `extern` and put the actual variable in gdt.c. You may wish to read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1433387/3857942

Comment: I figure there are global variables defined in header files leading to the other redefinition errors.

Comment: @MichaelPetch It's so weird though because this works on a non-arm machine

Comment: Maybe the non arm machine is using a  much older cross compiler or gcc toolchain that was more forgiving? On the non-arm machine what version of `gcc` and `ld` are you using?

Comment: I just cloned your Github repository on my x86-64 Ubuntu 22.04 system and ran the Makefile and it failed the same way with redefinition errors. I suspect your `ld` on the system it works is quite old.

Comment: Thank you so much for this @MichaelPetch. By any chance are you Brokenthorn?

Comment: Nooo I'm not Brokenthorn and I'm not associated with any of the OSdev tutorials.

Comment: Np, i thought you might be because he is named Mike to haha. I was wondering if you were on the StackOverflow chatrooms, Gitter or Skype for contact. I might need more help on this matter. I understand if your busy though, no worries!

Comment: You can also find me on the [OSdev Forum](https://forum.osdev.org/) or on Reddit r/osdev .